# Java 7 retrieve and read local file using fileinput stream

Tags: java, security, file-permissions, fileinputstream

How can i retrieve and read local file using fileinputstream using Java 7. Something like this but for a local file. With the new security settings, I cant get it to work

```
public static InputStream openReading(String file)
    throws FileNotFoundException
{
try
{
    PersistenceService pService = (PersistenceService) ServiceManager
            .lookup(PersistenceService.class.getCanonicalName());
    URL fileurl = new URL(getCode() + file);
    FileContents fc= pService.get(fileurl);
    fc.setMaxLength(10240000);
    InputStream in= fc.getInputStream();
    return stream;
}
catch (MalformedURLException m)
{
    m.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException f)
{   
    throw new FileNotFoundException(f.getMessage());   
}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `return new FileInputStream(file);` in place of your whole method body?

Comment: @DavidWallace Presumably the context is running from a signed but untrusted WebStart app. / `java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(file))` is the Java SE 7 way of doing things.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline the app is signed with a trusted certificate this metthod does not work as well

Comment: @user3375061 By "trusted certificate" do you mean a valid certificate. Even if the certificate is valid, it doesn't mean that the application is requesting full access to mess about as the local user (nor that the user permits that). / Not sure what you mean by "this method does not work as well". `Files.newInputStream` vs `new FileInputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExtendedService.openFile` is the equivalent for opening a file. That gives read/write access. There is no option to ask for read-only!

Comment: you comment above worked. Java 7 now uses Java.nio.file like you  showed...      Thanks  java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPa‌​th(file))